# asp.net Core 3.1 Webapp unable to bind to localhost

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel

i have an issue starting my asp.net core webapp with the profile "WebApp". i allways get:

"System.IO.IOException" in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Ein Ausnahmefehler des Typs "System.IO.IOException" ist in System.Private.CoreLib.dll aufgetreten.
Failed to bind to address https://localhost:5000.

The port is not used by any other programm. I tried lots of different ports as well.

Does anybody has an idea what i can try?
On my colleagues Pc it works just fine.

Seems it does not have the right to bind to any ports.

Startup:

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
       }
```

launchsettings.

````
     "iisSettings": {
         "windowsAuthentication": false,
         "anonymousAuthentication": true,
         "iisExpress": {
             "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:23736",
             "sslPort": 44369
         }
     },
     "profiles": {
         "IIS Express": {
             "commandName": "IISExpress",
             "launchBrowser": true,
             "environmentVariables": {
                 "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
             }
         },
         "WebApp": {
             "commandName": "Project",
             "launchBrowser": true,
             "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
             "environmentVariables": {
                 "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
             }
         }
     }
 }```

IIS Profile works fine for me..

Would be very glad if one could help. trying for few days now.
````

Comment: Have you tried to use http://localhost:5000 instead of https://localhost:5001. Besides, is there any other error message you have faced?

Comment: solved it. the error occured because the project was located on a network drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It was because the project was not located on my C-Drive but on a network drive from my company.

After moving it to the C drive it worked.